# optimize/vectorize code CUDA Matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu

my question is about vectorize my for loop in Matlab using CUDA.
This arrays are gpuArrays.
The main problem is that the array isn't completed at start and it's getting bigger with every k iteration. Also it is creating by previous probes from array.  Is it possbile to make this loop parallel/vectorize or any other way to optimize the code for CUDA to make it faster?

```
  for k=3:5000

    q_=gWmacierz((1:N_/2+1),k-1);
    p_d1_=[p0_;gWmacierz((N_/2+2:N_+1),k-1)];
    p_d2_=[gWmacierz((N_/2+2:N_+1),k-1);pN_];
    F_=arrayfun(@funkcja,q_,p_d1_,p_d2_);

    C1_=diag(F_+4*Gc);
    C_=[C1_ C2_;C3_ C4_];
    tic;
    if k>3000
        Wwektor = ginvA_* ((gB_*gWmacierz(:,k-2)) + (C_*gWmacierz(:,k-1))  + (gD_*gu01_) + (gE_*gu00_) - gQ*gleak);
    else
        Wwektor = ginvA_* ((gB_*gWmacierz(:,k-2)) + (C_*gWmacierz(:,k-1))  + (gD_*gu01_) + (gE_*gu00_));
    end
    toc;
    gWmacierz(:,k)= Wwektor;

end

Pin=(gWmacierz(N_/2+2,:)+gWmacierz(N_/2+3,:))/2;
Pout=(gWmacierz(N_,:)+gWmacierz(N_+1,:))/2;

for k=3:5000    
    q=gmacierz((1:N/2+1),k-1);
    p_d1=[Pin(k);gmacierz((N/2+2:N+1),k-1)];
    p_d2=[gmacierz((N/2+2:N+1),k-1);Pout(k)];
    F=arrayfun(@funkcja,q,p_d1,p_d2);
    C1=diag(F+4*Gc);
    C=[C1 C2;C3 C4];
    wektor = ginvA* ((gB*gmacierz(:,k-2)) + (C*gmacierz(:,k-1))  + (gD*[Pin(k-1);Pout(k-1)]) + (gE*[Pin(k);Pout(k)]));

    gmacierz=[gmacierz wektor];

end  
    Qin=(gWmacierz(2,:));
    Qout=(gWmacierz(N/2,:));

    Qin_ref=(gmacierz(1,:));
    Qout_ref=(gmacierz(N/2+1,:));
    deltaQin=Qin-Qin_ref;
    deltaQout=Qout-Qout_ref;
```

Comment: For starters, if you're working with the GPU you don't want to be constantly allocating memory as that is a very expensive operation on the gpu

Comment: GPU: Great for computation, terrible for memory management! If you want to optimize CUDA code: allocate all memory in the begging, try to use the less amount of sliced variables as possible

Comment: @Suever , Ander Biguri. I updated my code. But still the GPU code is much slower than CPU. Only if i use much bigger array they steel some time from CPU and they started to be competitor. Any ideas how could i optimize more my code? (array C is updating on every k so i have to allocate this every k iteration)